# In React Native image picker allow user to access camera from image picker

Tags: react-native

I'm writing an app in in React Native using Expo. I'm using expo-image-picker to allow users to upload images.
I see that there is an an option for the user to select images from the photo gallery(launchImageLibraryAsync) and an option for the user to use the camera to take a photo(launchCameraAsync). However, with most apps, if you have the photo gallery dialogue open there is usually an icon to switch to the camera, and vice versa, if you are in the camera, there is usually an icon to switch to the photo gallery.
This doesn't seem to be the case with expo-image-picker, if I'm in the camera there is no option to go directly to the photo gallery, and if you're in the camera, there is no option to do directly to the photo gallery.
I don't really want two separate button on my app to open both the gallery and the camera. Is there a way to switch between the photo gallery and the camera using expo-image-picker?

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing,  and have exactly the same question. did you find out any more?

Comment: @delboy1978uk sadly not. I ended up having to put two separate buttons on my app. If you find the answer do let me know

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by allowing my image input component have a mode, 'photos', 'camera', or 'both' (the default).

When you press the input, if it is 'both', it brings up an alert with camera/photos/cancel buttons, and launches the appropriate interface.

Here's my  code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Alert, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View} from "react-native";

import colors from '../config/colors'
import Icon from './Icon';
import useCamera from '../hooks/useCamera';
import usePhotos from '../hooks/usePhotos';

function ImageInput({imageUri, onChangeImage, onCancel = ()  => {}, mode = 'both'}) {

    const camera = useCamera();
    const photos = usePhotos();

    const handlePress = async () => {
        if (!imageUri) {
            switch (mode) {
                case 'camera':
                    selectImage('camera')
                    break;
                case 'photos':
                    selectImage('photos');
                    break;
                case 'both':
                default:
                    Alert.alert(
                        'Please choose',
                        null,
                        [
                            { text: 'Photos', onPress: () => selectImage('photos') },
                            { text: 'Camera', onPress: () => selectImage('camera') },
                            { text: 'Cancel', style: 'cancel' }
                        ]
                    );
            }

        } else {
            Alert.alert('Remove', 'are you sure you want to remove this image?', [
                { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => onChangeImage(null)},
                { text: 'No'},
            ]);
        }
    };

    const selectImage = async (pickerType) => {
        try {
            if (pickerType === 'camera') {
                const result = await camera.takePhoto({
                    allowsEditing: true,
                    quality: 0.5
                })
                result.canceled ? onCancel() : onChangeImage(result.assets[0].uri);

            } else {
                const result = await photos.selectImage({
                    quality: 0.5
                });
                result.canceled ? onCancel() : onChangeImage(result.assets[0].uri);
            }

        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('Image error', 'Error reading image');
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handlePress}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {!imageUri ? (
                    <Icon name="camera" size={75} iconColor={colors.medium} />
                ) : (
                    <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
                )}
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: colors.light,
        borderRadius: 15,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    }
})

export default ImageInput;
```

For clarity here are my useCamera and usePhotos hooks:

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

export default useCamera = () => {

    const requestPermission = async () => {
        const { granted } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

        if (!granted) {
            Alert.alert(
                'Device settings alert',
                'You need to allow camera permissions for this to work'
            );
        }
    }

    const takePhoto = async (options) => {
        options = {mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images, ...options };

        return await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync(options);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        requestPermission();
    }, []);

    return {takePhoto};
};
```

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

export default usePhotos = () => {

    const requestPermission = async () => {
        const { granted} = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

        if (!granted) {
            Alert.alert(
                'Device settings alert',
                'You need to allow media library permissions for this to work'
            );
        }
    }

    const selectImage = async (options) => {
        options = {mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images, ...options };

        return await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync(options);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        requestPermission();
    }, []);

    return {selectImage};
};
```

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing. Frustrating because I really wanted the button to switch to camera from the gallery like every other app. Never mind, it's not the end of the world..

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Swift code of expo-image-picker module in `node_modules/expo-image-picker/ios/ImagePickerModule.swift` and found it uses `UIImagePickerController` ([see Apple's official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller))

Unfortunately there's no way of doing this even at Swift level, nothing short with the expo package. You would have to build the interface yourself. The apps that do this actually implement their own Camera+Library views! I've seen some apps doing this and every app looks totally different which means it's something each app has to provide. I'd recommend against this.

I also found that many apps uses an approach that users find familiar so no worry about UX. Just display an ActionSheet, you can use [expo/react-native-action-sheet](https://github.com/expo/react-native-action-sheet) that shows options (Take photo / Existing photo / Cancel)

[image]